# return model to view on error with selectlistitem default value

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have some issues with default value of my dropdownlist when returning my model to view in case of one or many errors. I have a dropdownlist in the view which is filled from the controller and others empty dropdownlists in the same view which are filled with JSON on selection of the first dropdownlist.

```
    public ActionResult Countriesdata()
    {       
    CountrydetailsViewModel vm= new CountrydetailsViewModel();
        vm.countries= dal.countries().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.CountryID.ToString() })
                               .ToList();
   return View(vm);
    }
```

here, dal is my data access layer and allows me to fill the list of countries from the database. The code use to fill the countries list in the view is like this

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedcountry, new  SelectList(Model.countries, "Value", "Text", Model.selectedcountry), "-Select a Country-", new { @class = "ddlist" })
```

one of the empty dropdowlists is as the one below

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.selectedtown, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Value", "Text", Model.selectedtown), "-Select a Town/City-", new { @class = "ddlist" })
```

This code work very well i reach the page for the first time because i have set a default value for country dropdownlist which is select a country. i use the following code to post my form.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Countriesdata(CountrydetailsViewModel  returnmodel)
    {       
     if (! ModelState.IsValid)
        {
  returnmodel.countries= dal.countries().Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.CountryID.ToString() })
                               .ToList();
   return View(returnmodel);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("mainpage");
    }
```

If the form contains errors, my model is returned back to my view with the posted value of country selected dropdownlist as default, which is not my goal because the others dropdowlists which are filled using JSON on the country dropdownlist selection change are empty.Thus, I ought to select this same country once to fill the others dropdowlists, which is cumbersome. To be logic, i would like to send back my model to my view with default value of the dropdowlist of country when an error occurs. I am using MVC4 and VS 2010

Answer (score 1):

You need to populate both `SelectList`'s in the controller methods so they get passed to the view. In the GET method, the 2nd one will be an empty `SelectList` (assuming its a 'Create' metod), but in the POST method it will be populated based on the country that has been selected.

You model should include

```
public class CountrydetailsViewModel
{
    [Required(Error Message = "..")]
    public int? SelectedCountry { get; set; }
    [Required(Error Message = "..")]
    public int? SelectedTown { get; set; }
    ....
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CountryList{ get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TownList { get; set; }
}
```

And your controller methods

```
public ActionResult Countriesdata()
{
    CountrydetailsViewModel vm = new CountrydetailsViewModel();
    ConfigureViewModel(vm);
    return View(vm);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Countriesdata(CountrydetailsViewModel returnmodel)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ConfigureViewModel(returnmodel);
        return View(returnmodel); 
    }
    .... // save and redirect
}
private ConfigureViewModel(CountrydetailsViewModel model)
{
    var countries = dal.countries();
    model.CountryList= countries.Select(x => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = x.Name,
        Value = x.CountryID.ToString() 
    });
    if (model.SelectedCountry.HasValue)
    {
        // adjust query to suit your property names
        var towns = db.towns.Where(e => e.CountryId == model.SelectedCountry);
        model.TownList = towns.Select(x => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = x.Name,
            Value = x.TownID.ToString()   
        });
    }
    else
    {
        model.TownList = new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>());
    }
}
```

This also allows you to generate the correct options and default selections when editing an existing `CountrydetailsViewModel`.

Then in the view, use

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCountry, Model.CountryList, "-Select a Country-", new { @class = "ddlist" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedCountry)

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTown, Model.TownList, "-Select a Country-", new { @class = "ddlist" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedTown)
```

Note that there is no point creating an identical `SelectList` from the original one you passed to the view by using `new SelectList(..)` - its just unnecessary extra overhead. Note also that the last parameter in the `SelectList` constructor is ignored when your binding to a model property (internally the method builds its own `SelectList` based on the value of the property) - you could put whatever value you wanted as the last parameter and you will see that the option is still correct selected based on the value of the property.

Comment: +1 for @Stephen Muecke, i have implemented your code according to my need and it walk like a charm. Many thanks

Comment: Then perhaps you should consider accepting the answer to close this out (and other answers to you questions including you own answers that solved the problem)